# What is the polar form of $-6i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

The module of $-6i$ is $6$ (the square root of $36$), but $ \tan\theta = -\cfrac{6}{0}$, meaning that the polar form $ 6(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta) $ is also indefinite?

Comment: We have $\cos\theta=0$ and $\sin\theta=-1$, so the angle is $3\pi/2$, or a relative.

Comment: Why noy take $\theta=1\frac{1}{2}\pi$?

Comment: @NickyHekster:  That's exactly what I did, using $3\pi/2$, which if I had not been lazy I would have written as $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.  The "mixed number" notation you used is seldom used in mathematics.

Comment: @André Nicolas - We answered exactly at the same time! Maybe in the Anglo-saxon countries what you call "mixed number" notation is not used, but in my country (the Netherlands) for example current high school text books, it is used.

Comment: @NickyHekster: In North American schools, mixed number notation is certainly used, as in $1\frac{1}{2}$ hours, or miles. It is much rarer in more mathematical contexts.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need $\tan$, you need angle. Just look for the angle in complex plane. It is $\theta = \frac {3\pi} 2$. So, $\cos \theta = 0$ and $\sin \theta = -1$, $-6i = 6 i \sin \frac {3\pi} 2$. Or just use [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

You know $r=|-6i|=6.$  Now putting this into polar form we have
$$-6i=6(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\implies -i=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\implies \cos\theta=0\ \text{and}\sin\theta=-1\implies\quad \theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$$